# File manager with two panel synchronized directory browsing

Tags: nautilus, filemanager, midnight-commander, vifm

Is there any tool (similar to vifm, mc) which allows two panel synchronized directory browsing?

eg. I have two directories opened in both panels:

`/home/user/website1/`

and

`/home/user/website2/`

and when I navigate down to `/home/user/website1/public` I want the second pane also be changed to `/home/user/website2/public`

This is more or less the behavior FileZilla FTP client has.

Comment: Filezilla itself?

Comment: @muru, could be, but I don't know how to open local directories in both panes.

Answer (score 2):

Filezilla can do it, if one connects via ssh to localhost.

I tried Double Commander, Midnight Commander, Dolphin and Krusader, but couldn't find a similar feature.